# How can I enforce that a certain C# type is never used as a statement?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I'm using a promise library that requires every promise chain to eventually be terminated by a `.Done()` call. The problem is that it's quite easy to forget it, and when that happens exceptions from within promises are swallowed which is quite bad.

i.e. these are all ok:

```cs
DoThingThatReturnsAPromise()
    .Then(() => Log("Finished") // <-- returns IPromise
    .Done(); // <-- void method. Everything ok, error handler attached
```

```cs
IPromise DoThing()
{
    return DoOtherThing(); // Also ok, the calling method should make sure to use the return value though
}
```

Incorrect usage would be:

```cs
DoThingThatReturnsAPromise()
    .Then(() => Log("Finished"); // <-- WRONG! We're leaving the IPromise as a statement, not attaching error handler
```

```cs
void DoThing()
{
    DoThingThatReturnsPromise();
}
```

JetBrain's `MustUseReturnValue` attribute does almost what I want... It's just that I'd have to go through every method that returns a Promise (there are A LOT) and add it. Also, whenever somebody on my team writes a new function that returns an `IPromise`, they will probably forget to add it.

TL;DR:

I guess what I'm looking for is a way to tag a certain type (in this case IPromise) value, and detect if it's used as a statement. i.e. the last thing before a `;` so I can add a linting rule for it.

Comment: Can you catch the behavior with unit tests?

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer, but this is pretty similar in functionality to Resharper's [ConfigureAwait checker](https://github.com/aelij/ConfigureAwaitChecker).  Maybe this leads you in the right direction?  Good luck.

Comment: Not sure what will cause more headache, but you can write your own [Roslyn analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [Roslyn analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019) are for. In fact, there are a couple already written for "things that must use the return value of things" in the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers` package:

- one that checks that `IDisposable` objects are eventually disposed.
- one that checks that `Linq` statements that don't materialize the sequence are eventually materialized (this is very close to yours, it's things like `arr.Select(x => x + 1);`)

You can look at their source code for inspiration if you wish and write your own promise code analyzer that you can then reference from any project where you wish it to run.

Comment: That is the answer to your question, though if you prefer a solution to your actual problem (the fact that you need to call `Done()` like a monkey on every statement), it's simple: ditch your library and use the TPL and proper `await`/`async` code. There's absolutely no reason to need that `Done()` at the end of a promise but bad code.

Comment: If you decide to write your own analyzer, I suggest you read [this article](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0399/). It contains basic info about using Roslyn and working with syntax trees and semantic information. I think information from the article is enough to write your own analyzer that can detect cases from your message.
You can use a syntax tree to detect that the return value of an expression isn't used. To detect that an expression is of the `IPromise` type, you can use semantic information (`SemanticModel`).